# Compiled Single output file typescript is trying to load node modules in browser

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have a tsconfig file which builds a frontend typescript application to a single output:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "lib": [
            "es2015",
            "es2015.iterable",
            "dom"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outFile": "output.js",
        "strict": true
    }
}
```

I am loading the output in the browser using the `<script>` tags and i am using systemjs [https://jspm.io/system@0.19.34.js] with the snippet to bootstrap the application:

```
SystemJS.import("Application")
    .then((module) => {
        console.log(module);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

My understanding of how i've compiled the application is that all npm dependencies should be built into the `output.js` file. However this is not the case I in the inspector that the browser is trying to load the `lodash` module at `https://registry.jspm.io/lodash.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> all npm dependencies should be built into the output.js file

No it is not. Typescript compile's output file only affects code for project, not for any modules imported in those code. If you'd like to have bundle for browser you should use bundler like webpack, etcs.

Comment: Are there any specific resources you'd recommend. I'm trying to navigate these waters? I've been playing around with webpack without much success. Is webpack supposed to replace the tsc compilation? I'm a little confused as to the usual steps required or the standard workflow

Comment: webpack isn't replacement to compiler - what tsc does is typescript compilation while other does generate bundle for javascript. if you haven't experienced one before and would like to understand concept, worth to read introduction of webpack, or any other bundler supposed to work with less configuration then webpack. also there are large numbers of xxxx-webpack-quickstart examples you can reference existing configs.

Comment: Would I need to use the SystemJS bundler instead of webpack since I'm using the `system` module in my tsconfig? I'm just not sure if the way I'm intending to build the application is correct. My understanding of what is going on or what I'm trying to achieve is: 

1. Build `*.ts` with the above `.tsconfig` into single output 
2. use a bundler to include all the npm modules into a `bundle.js` file
3. include that `bundle.js` in a `<script>` tag before the `output.js` in my static page

Comment: I solved the issue after about 6 hours. I ripped and tweaked the `webpack.config.js` and `tsconfig.json` from the https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed for my own purposes. I stripped out all the angular stuff so it would work for me .